# livevalidation.js custom username check function

Tags: php, jquery, validation, livevalidation

I am sure this is probably something simple that i am not doing.  Running livevalidation.js jquery plugin (livevalidation.com). It provides for custom function callbacks.  I am trying to check for username availability.  The server side is working fine and I am getting the proper responses back in my data var...

Here is my JS:

```
Validate.Username = function(value, paramsObj) {
    var paramsObj = paramsObj || {};
    var message = paramsObj.failureMessage || "Username is not available";
    var isSuccess = true;

    $.post("<?php echo fURL::getDomain(); ?>/ajax/username", 
        function(data) {
            if (data.status === 'notavailable')
            {
            Validation.fail('oops, not available.');
            }               
            });
};
```

I am calling it using:

```
var username = new LiveValidation('username', { validMessage: curr_username + "is available!" });
username.add( Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: "Choose a username" });
username.add( Validate.Username, { failureMessage: "Username is not available." } );
```

The problem I am getting is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Validation is not defined
```

If I put the `Validation.fail()` outside of my `.post()` function it works fine. So am pretty sure it is because it's not able to be referenced inside the `.post()` function.

I've tried using a callback function

```
if (data.status === 'notavailable')
{
    status_not_available();
}
```

I get the same error.

I realize this is something probably extremely simple, but any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am having the same issue.
Ive found the following, http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajax-return-value-on-success-or-error-with-livevalidation but have not been able to get it working.
BUT YES! At this very moment i made som (crappy) javascript addon that made it behave, i think :)

This is what i use.

```
        function check_avail(name, id, postUrl)
    {
       var dataVal = name+'='+$(id).val();
       var isaccepted = ''
       $(id).next('div').remove();

       $(id).after("Undersøger om "+name+" er ledigt");

       $.ajax({
          url: postUrl,
          cache: false,
          type: 'post',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: dataVal,
          async:  false,
          success: function(data) {
             if( data.success == 'true' )
             {
                $('#'+name+'-availability').remove();
                //return false;
           isaccepted = false;
             }

             if( data.success == 'false' )
             {
                $('#'+name+'-availability').remove();
    //            name.destroy();
            isaccepted = true;
             }
          }

       });

    if (isaccepted == false) {
    return false;   
    } else{
    return true
    };

    }
```

And

```
    f1.add( Validate.Custom, { against: function() {
     return check_avail( 'brugernavn', '#ft001', 'usernamecheck.asp' ); 
    }, failureMessage: 'Brugernavnet er optaget' } );
```

Hope it helps you :)
The json query you can read about on the link in the begining :)
(I am not at all skilled at javascript, and the "isaccepted" solution could problalby be made a lot better)

Comment: That works great. The only thing is getting it to do this without asych off.... I've been reading up on doing a synchronous request, and from what I read it is a bad thing to do because it can lock up the browser ui until the request has been finished.

Comment: Oh, i have no solution for that, but please, if you find one - Write it here.

Answer (score 0):

try to change it from Validation.fail to Validate.fail

try wrapping it in another function and try putting your validateStatus(status) function both inside and outside your Validate.Username function. example below is inside

```
Validate.Username = function(value, paramsObj) {
var paramsObj = paramsObj || {};
var message = paramsObj.failureMessage || "Username is not available";
var isSuccess = true;

$.post("<?php echo fURL::getDomain(); ?>/ajax/username", 
    function(data) {
          validateStatus(data.status);      
        });

function validateStatus(status){
     if (status === 'notavailable'){
           Validate.fail("not available");
      }
}

};
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.... yeah sorry, that was a typo, it was supposed to be Validate.fail().... With Validate.fail() instead of the Reference Error i get:

`Uncaught [object Object]
Validate.failplugins.js:6
(anonymous function)signup:134
f.extend._Deferred.e.resolveWithjquery.min.js:16
wjquery.min.js:18
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.djquery.min.js:18`

I am pretty sure it's because I am trying to access the object withing the jquery function and it is outside of it's scope....

How can I put it in scope?

Thank you again in advance.

Comment: if you try and change it to this.fail or $(this).fail does that work?

Comment: That didn't do the trick either. Here is what I did. To me it seems sloppy, so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  This starts inside the `function(data) {`  if (data.status === 'notavailable')  {  $('#username').next().text('username is not available.').removeClass('LV_valid').addClass('LV_invalid');  $('#username').removeClass('LV_valid_field').addClass('LV_invalid_field');  }

Comment: sorry, I can't seem to figure out the formatting in the comments.